# CocoaPods $PODS_ROOT environment variable equivalent in Swift Packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I want to update a private library from CocoaPods to Swift Packages.
During the Build Phase I use a Run Script where the environment variable $PODS_ROOT is used, like this:

```
cat "$PODS_ROOT/myLibrary/...."
```

What is the equivalent root path for Swift Packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific environment variable for Swift Packages in XCode but you can build a path to your package dependency from `BUILD_DIR` e.g.:

```sh
swiftPackageDir=${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/SwiftPackageName/
```

Where `SwiftPackageName` is a name of your dependency.

Comment: this works great for regular builds, but fails for archive builds unfortunately

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon I've made the appropriate fix in the script for archiving. Thanks for your notice.